# Import Google Play services as extern library in Android

Tags: android, service, import

I've added Google Play Library to my project as an extern library including it in the "libs" folder (I know about th SDK Manager plugin feature, but it's not what I need).

Then I add it on the dependencies in the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/google_play_services.jar')
}
```

I've cleaned up the project, synchronized de Gradle... but when I try to call any import from this library on my classes (As the same way I'd do if it'll be added with SDK Manager) I get errors at every import call.

[Not recognising libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF3nT.png)

[Package errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq4mV.png)

Thank you, guys.

Comment: Try this   `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

Comment: Google Play services is not delivered as a jar anymore - it is an AAR with resources, manifests, etc. Why aren't you using those?

Comment: why are you trying to use the jar and not a gradle dependency

Comment: Because of dumb enterprise rules.

@Raghunandan answer works, but still get an error with 1 import. Maybe I've got an old .jar. Gonna try finding an AAR and tell you.